# Ubuntu 22.04 random quick ui/input freeze

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I’m experiencing random fast UI/input freezes. They are most noticeable while typing quickly. The UI/input just freezes for no more than a second. The freeze is really fast but it results in a very bad experience like wrong clicks and duplicate letters. I tried switching intel/nvidia gpu and xorg/wayland but no effect at all.

Does anybody has experience something like it?

**Update:**

As requested in comments here are more details:
It is a laptop. I'm experiencing the issue with any keyboard (laptop's and the 4 externals that I tried).
I haven't tried using "Try Ubuntu" because of several reasons.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to "debug" it but I don't know where to start. Isn't there some "UI" logs and I can search for?

Meanwhile I'm pretty confident that re-installation will fix it but I would like to avoid it for now.

Comment: yes, I had, I simply reinstalled (because I also did not get a response here....)

Comment: A hardware problem maybe? Loose contacts? Is this a desktop or a laptop? If laptop, does it work if you connect an external keyboard and mouse? Does is work if you boot from the Ubuntu installation USB and use the try Ubuntu option? Does it work if you boot Windows (if you have dual boot)? Edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: I've updated my post as requested

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was few docker containers that were unable to start successfully and were constantly restarting themselves. After stopping these containers the problems was solved.